# What is the recommended or optimal method to store hexadecimal data in an Access table, and subsequently retrieve it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, hex

I've got multiple functions that use hexadecimal for either color or unicode data (e.g., unicode 2713 for a checkmark, FF9933 for a yellow-orangish color).  I'm now trying to optimize this by putting it into a variables table, but:

1. other than using a basic text field, I don't know the how to store hexadecimal data, and
2. if I store it as text, then I'm getting errors when I try to process it as unicode (e.g., ChrW(&H2713) works, but ChrW(&H + variable_datum) throws an error).

So, what is the best way to store hexadecimal data in a MS Access 2007 table?
And, what is the optimal corresponding method to pull the data out and use it a hexadecimal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store a hexadecimal value in a regular numeric field, then when you need it as a hexadecimal value, use the Hex() function to convert it.

OTOH, if your variable_datum is a text data type field which stores the hexadecimal representation of a number, you can feed it to the ChrW() like this:

```
ChrW("&H" & variable_datum)
```

I don't know if this is causing extra confusion, but I think &HFF9933 (or 16750899 decimal) is outside the Unicode character space range.  So ChrW(&HFF9933) should throw error #5 (Invalid procedure call or argument), same as if you try ChrW(16750899) or ChrW(16750899&).

I don't know which approach is best.  I would probably store the decimal equivalent in a numeric field.  However, if you have a need to see it in the table as hexadecimal, store it in a text field.

Comment: Because I'm giving users the ability to edit a hexadecimal color or unicode value, I went with the text data storage and the 'ChrW("&H" & variable_datum)'.    Thank you!

Comment: You could still store the decimal value, and just use an unbound textbox to edit the Hex value. You'd have to have the OnCurrent event of your form populate the unbound textbox with the Hex() equivalent of the stored decimal value, and then use the textbox's AfterUpdate event to write the edited Hex value back to the decimal field.